# JTree does not show up

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Why the JTree does not show up? Here is my code:

```
    initComponents();
    JTree treeView;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("myBooks");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Drama");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode book1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Macbeth");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode book2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Hamlet");
    category.add(book1);
    category.add(book2);
    top.add(category);
    treeView = new JTree(top);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(treeView);
    mainPanel.add(pane);
```

Comment: @Snicolas, I set the background to red but didn't solve the problem. treeView.setBackground(Color.red);

Comment: That's just way to help see what's going on. Also try changing the layout manager used by `mainPanel`, as @Hovercraft suggests.

Comment: I feel a little embarrassed saying this since you've just got good tips from 3 GUI gurus, but.. for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend on Snicolas' answer (1+ to him) you appear to be adding the JScrollPane to your mainPanel without regard for the layout manager used. I'm guessing that your GUI is using the GroupLayout, and if so, I suggest you use a layout manager that is more user friendly.  Also, are you adding the pane JScrollPane after pack and setVisible(true) are called on the top-level window? If so you'll need to revalidate and repaint the container that is receiving the new component.

Comment: You are right, the problem was with the GroupLayout. Once changed to FlowLayout, the JTree showed up. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, but I just have to note that I rarely use FlowLayout as it is one of the weakest of the layout managers.

Comment: offers less customization let's say. BorderLayout maybe more suited here

Answer (score 5):

Give your `JTree` a background and see what space it occupies on screen. Also you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> on a swing app and see the different components in console with size, position and everything.

My guess is that `mainPanel` doesn't have a good layout or the jtree should have a decent preferred size set.

Comment: *"you can use CTRL + SHIFT + F1.."*  Brilliant!  Where did you pick up that pearl of wisdom?